# How to swap table values to column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE A

```
P         Q            R
1         A            a
2         B            a
3         C            b
4         D            b
```

How can I convert it to

Table B

```
P         a            b
1         A            -
2         B            -
3         -            C
4         -            D
```

Hint: a is mapped with A&B not with C&D in table A. Similarly b is mapped with C&D not with A&B. Pivot is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved using a Dynamic CrossTab. For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    P   INT,
    Q   CHAR(1),
    R   CHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO SampleData
    SELECT 1, 'A', 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'B', 'a' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'C', 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'D', 'b'
```

**Dynamic Crosstab**

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = '',
        @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = '',
        @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    P' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN R = ''' + R + ''' THEN Q END) AS [' + R + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT R FROM SampleData
)t
ORDER BY R

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM SampleData
GROUP BY P
ORDER BY P
'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**RESULT**

```
P           a    b
----------- ---- ----
1           A    NULL
2           B    NULL
3           NULL C
4           NULL D
```

Comment: Thanks but the column number as well as the contents can vary depends on situations... i.e A,B,C,D can varies upto any digit and a,b,c,d also can be varied.. so I can't use hard code or Case on it...

Comment: You could use a dynamic crosstab.See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select P, 
case when R='a' then a else '-' end as a,
case when R='b' then '-' else a end as b
from table_A
```